# Java - Groovy : regex parse text block

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I know that this is a common question and I've been through a lot of forums to figure out whats the problem in my code.

I have to read a text file with several blocks in the following format:

```
import com.myCompanyExample.gui.Layout

/*some comments here*/

@Layout
LayoutModel currentState() {
   MyBuilder builder = new MyBuilder()
   form example
     title form{
        row_1
        row_1 
        row_n
      }
   return build.get()
}

@Layout
LayoutModel otherState() {
   ....
   ....
   return build.get()
}
```

I have this code to read all the file and I'd like to extract each block between the keyword "@Layout" and the keyword "return". I need also to catch all newline so later I'll be able to split each matched block into a list

```
private void myReadFile(File fileLayout){
    String line = null;
    StringBuilder allText = new StringBuilder();
    try{
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileLayout);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            allText.append(line)
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file");
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file");
    }
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)@Layout.*?return",Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(allText);
    while(matcher.find()){
       String [] layoutBlock = (matcher.group()).split("\\r?\\n")
      for(index in layoutBlock){
           //check each line of the current block
      }
}
```

layoutBlock returns size=1

Comment: Are you sure that `layoutBlock` length is 1? I have run the same code and it works (`layoutBlock` contains matched lines)

Comment: Why not try to parse the script and interrogate the class normally, rather than trying to write a regular expression to read groovy scripts?

Comment: @cybersoft
I think that `layoutBlock` has just one element which is the entire block returned from the matcher find, and that's fine. Now I not able to split that string on each newline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can potentially be a so called XY problem anyway...if the groovy source is composed only by `@Layout` annotated blocks of code you can use a tempered greedy token to select till the next annotation (view [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/pS4qS0/1)).

Change the pattern loc as this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "@Layout(?:(?!@Layout).)*", Pattern.DOTALL );
```

*PS*: the dotall flag `(?s)` inside the regex and the parameter `Pattern.DOTALL` do the same thing (enable the so called *multiline* mode), use only one of them indifferently.

**UPDATE**

I tried your code, the problem (preserving newline) is in the method you use to slurp the file (`bufferedReader.readline()` remove the newline at the end of the string).

Simply readd a newline when append to `allText`:

```
String ln = System.lineSeparator();
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    allText.append(line + ln);
}
```

Or you can replace all the code to slurp the file with this:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

//can throw an IOException
String filePath = "/path/to/layout.groovy";
String allText = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)),StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: You're right, `readLine()` was removing newline. 
Thank you for your help